# When should one use a closed interval and when an open one in inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

In the following solution:

[image: Solution]

In case I, the person has taken $2x \geq 0$ and then solved the equation. For the other inequality, he has taken $3 - x \gt 0$ and then solved the equation.

My question is, if it's the case that we want to get the value of $x$ based on the fact that either the numerator is positive and denominator is negative or numerator is negative and denominator is positive, then why are we using $\geq$ in one case and only $\gt$ in another? Shouldn't it be $\gt$ in both?

Comment: $2x=0$ still satisfies the inequality, that's why. On the other hand the denominator can not be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple fact is that you have to consider all cases. Why do we have to split into cases in the first place? Because at some point we want to multiply both sides of the inequality
$$\tag1 \frac{3+x}{3-x}\ge1$$
with $3-x$  and that is problematic: If this number is positive then nothing happens; but if it is negative then the order is reversed; and if it is zero we have bigger problems anyway.

I would not be happy with a case distinction $2x\ge 0$ vs. $2x\le 0$, not  because the cases overlap (which is not a problem a priori), but rather because that case actually still uses a case distinction by the sign of $3-x$ under the hood. So this is what I'd consider more stringent:

The complete case distinction would be a) $x<3$; b) $x=3$; c) $x>3$. Note that for all $x\in \Bbb R$, exactly one of the cases applies, i.e., this case distinction is *complete*.
Case b) can be excluded as then division by $3-x$ ($=0$) in the given inequality is not defined.

In case a), multiplication by $3-x$ yields
$$3+x\ge3-x, $$
which we readily transform to
$$\tag2 x\ge 0.$$ 
In case c), multiplication by $3-x$ yields
$$3+x\le3-x$$
instead,
which we readily transform to
$$\tag3 x\le 0.$$ 
So by combining the cases, $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$ (x<3\land x\ge 0)\quad\lor\quad (x>3\land x\le 0)$$
and as the conditions in the second half of this cannot be fulfilled, this can be simplified to 
$$ x<3\land x\ge 0.$$

So we notice that the strict inequality in the condition $x<3$ comes from the case $3-x=0$ being "forbidden", whereas the $\ge$ in the second condition ultimately goes back to the $\ge$ in $(1)$.